# Library issue in the project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, sockets, configuration, network-programming

I am getting very strange errors and i am not able to understand what these errors actually mean when build my project in visual studio it gives me the following errors can anybody tells me what actually these error means i though that there are some configuration issues i am doing socket programming and network programming.

Here are the bunch of error your help weill be highly appreciated....

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(E:\Study\FWIF\demola\ext-libs\libcommoncpp2-1.6.0\w32\Debug\ccgnu2.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (E:\Study\FWIF\demola\ext-libs\libcommoncpp2-1.6.0\w32\Debug\CapeCommon14.dll). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(992,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(ccgnu2) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (CapeCommon14). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>     Creating library E:\Study\FWIF\demola\ext-libs\libcommoncpp2-1.6.0\w32\Debug\CapeCommon14.lib and object E:\Study\FWIF\demola\ext-libs\libcommoncpp2-1.6.0\w32\Debug\CapeCommon14.exp
1>socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct sockaddr const *)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NPBUsockaddr@@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::operator==(struct sockaddr const *)const " (??8IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NPBUsockaddr@@@Z)
1>in6addr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct sockaddr const *)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NPBUsockaddr@@@Z)
1>inaddr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct sockaddr const *)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NPBUsockaddr@@@Z)
1>peer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct sockaddr const *)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NPBUsockaddr@@@Z)
1>simplesocket.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct sockaddr const *)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NPBUsockaddr@@@Z)
1>socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct in_addr const &)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NABUin_addr@@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::operator==(struct in_addr const &)const " (??8IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NABUin_addr@@@Z)
1>in6addr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct in_addr const &)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NABUin_addr@@@Z)
1>inaddr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct in_addr const &)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NABUin_addr@@@Z)
1>peer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct in_addr const &)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NABUin_addr@@@Z)
1>simplesocket.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct in_addr const &)const " (?isMember@IPV4Cidr@ost@@QBE_NABUin_addr@@@Z)
1>E:\Study\FWIF\demola\ext-libs\libcommoncpp2-1.6.0\w32\Debug\CapeCommon14.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
2>------ Build started: Project: buffer, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  buffer.cpp
2>e:\study\fwif\demola\ext-libs\libcommoncpp2-1.6.0\demo\buffer.cpp(41): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cc++/buffer.h': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I formatted the build errors by selecting and hitting the code icon (101010).  Same goes for code included in questions.  Easier to read now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the errors in project 1, it looks like you have to add a library to the build to resolve the function call `ost::IPV4Cidr::isMember(struct sockaddr const *)const`.  Possibly you are compiling with the wrong calling conventions for a library that you already included.

For the compile error in project `buffer`, you need to add the include path for that file `cc++/buffer.h` to the project.